# libCurl FTP authentication packets not sending

Tags: c++, ftp, libcurl

I'm trying to connect to an ftp server(using a domain name), login, and the upload a file to that server(it's my server). Here's the code I'm using(based off of the examples on the libcurl website).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

#ifdef WIN32
#include <io.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif


#define LOCAL_FILE "//home//uploadThis"
#define UPLOAD_FILE_AS "uploading-as"
#define RENAME_FILE_TO "uploadedFile" UPLOAD_FILE_AS
#define REMOTE_URL "myftpserver"

static size_t read_callback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) 
{
    curl_off_t nread;

    size_t retcode = fread(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);

    nread = (curl_off_t)retcode;

    return retcode;
}



int main(int argv, char *argc[])
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    FILE *hd_src;
    struct stat file_info;
    curl_off_t fsize;

    struct curl_slist *headerlist=NULL;
    static const char buf1[] = "RNFR " UPLOAD_FILE_AS;
    static const char buf2[] = "RNTO " RENAME_FILE_TO;

    fsize = (curl_off_t)file_info.st_size;

    hd_src = fopen(LOCAL_FILE, "rb");

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) 
    {
        headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, buf1);
        headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, buf2);


        const char *userpass = "username:password";
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, read_callback);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, REMOTE_URL);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE, headerlist);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, hd_src);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 21);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, userpass);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        curl_slist_free_all(headerlist);

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    fclose(hd_src);

    curl_global_cleanup();

    return 0;

}
```

My problem, is that as soon as I run the program, I connect to the ftp(I see the welcome banner), and then I get like 5 "530 Please login with USER and PASS." messages, and then they keep stacking up. I was completely puzzled, and I've tried every single possible way of authentication(including the creds in the url, using deprecated functions from previous versions, etc, etc), to no avail. I got curious, and opened wireshark. The only request being sent from my computer is the PUT command, and there is no login stuff going on at all. Any ideas? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL does not specify the protocol. It needs to start with FTP:// for it to be an FTP server.

Without a specified protocol, libcurl *guesses* based on the name and it then mostly will pick HTTP - which it seems to have done in your case.

Also as a general hint: enable [CURLOPT_VERBOSE](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_VERBOSE.html) to get to see the full protocol conversation. It helps you detect and fix problems faster.

Comment: I tried that, and again checked wireshark. With adding the ftp://, I was able to send the login packets. However, in the program, the cursor just blinks for a few seconds and then the program ends. I'm thinking that maybe that's a problem with the uploading functions? Not sure, but thank you for your continued help

Comment: Then enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE and check the commands and responses to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Wow...that option is extremely helpful, I was able to get all the kinks figured out because I could actually see what was going on...thanks. You should include that in your answer, for future viewers of this question